# Unable to figure out why input parameter is becoming null

Tags: javascript, grails, gsp

This is the script I have in my gsp page:

```
<script>
function getItemsLength(){
    var id = document.getElementsByName("franchiseID")[0].value(); 
    alert(id); //This displays the intended id
    var itemLength = ${storeCommand.numOfBranches(id)}; //The id becomes null when sent here
} 
</script>
```

This function is called onclick for a button, I cannot access the id through the store command itself, since the page hasn't been saved yet - it appears as null. Essentially I take in an ID the user gives me for the franchise, and I query to see how many stores have that franchiseID to display it on the screen.

I am new to grails and web development, so let me know if there is anything I am doing wrong!

Comment: `value` isn't a function. You should be getting an error on the line that assigns `id`.

Comment: There's no function `getElementByName`, it's `getElementsByName`. You've obviously made copying errors when you posted the question, so how can we tell what your real problem is.

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental issue you have here is you are trying to mix client-side programming and server-side programming. `${storeCommand.numBranches(id)}` is processed when the HTML is rendered and in that case `id` is not in scope.